Can I make requests over the network during the build phase of a docker container
I am new to Docker and trying to dockerize my NextJS app. The issue is that it must make calls to my Node/Express backend (also running in a container) to create static pages.
The backend starts without problems and is accessible from outside of the container, I have tested this with Postman.
When I run npm run build (which is "next build") in my frontend container, it cannot access the backend.
Here is my current config:
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
      network: app-network
    environment:
      - PORT=8000
      - NODE_ENV=production
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./client
      args:
        - SERVER_URL=http://backend:8000
    environment:
      - SERVER_URL=http://backend:8000
      - FRONTEND_URL=http://frontend:3000
      - NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env.local
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - backend

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile for frontend:
FROM node:20-alpine3.19 

WORKDIR /app

ARG SERVER_URL
ENV SERVER_URL=$SERVER_URL

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

RUN apk add --no-cache curl
RUN echo $SERVER_URL && curl --fail "$SERVER_URL/users/nextUserId" || (echo "Backend is not reachable" && exit 1)

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Dockerfile for backend:
FROM node:20-alpine3.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

To build and start the containers I am running this script:
docker-compose up -d backend


until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail
http://localhost:8000/users/nextUserId); do
echo "Waiting for backend to be available..."
sleep 5 done
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose build frontend

I am using DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 because buildkit does not support specifying network: app-network under build in docker-compose.yml.

An image build can never call into another container.  Nextjs app can't fetch data for SSG from running backend service (container), build failed with Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND is a very similar symptom but doesn't really have a resolution.  If the page data depends on results from the running backend, is it really "static"?  What would happen if you changed the backend implementation but kept running the same frontend image without rebuilding it?

Have you tried to create script that will call the server and then execute npm run command? So curl instead of being part of building would be activity that executes whenever you start your container.

@DavidMaze If I have 100 words in a dictionary (on my backend) and am building a dictionary I can define an endpoint that gives me all those words. NextJS can then generate a static page for all those words which speeds up the website. That's why it needs to make calls to the backend. Just one example.
But if you're saying that I can't make calls over the network during build phase, why can I set a network in my docker-compose.yml under build like this:
services:
service_name:
build:
network: network_name

@ArekKubiński Not sure what you mean exactly. The curl in the Dockerfile was my attempt to test whether I can access the backend when building the NestJS app, it's not needed.
